# InMemoryAuthentication cannot verify the provided CSRF token and return Whitelabel error page

Tags: jsp, authentication, spring-boot, spring-security

In a Spring Boot securityproject I get a Whitelabel Error Page when trying to be redirected from the login (after typed username and password) to the chosen page. The details are if I begin with the views that are jsp-files.
The `start.jsp` only have one purpose, to redirect to `test.jsp`

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-
            8859-1">
        <title>Startpage</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Click <a href="/test">here</a> Start.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

The securitysetting for `start.jsp` is permitAll and the setting for `test.jsp` is authenticated so before `test.jsp` `login.jsp` will be called to type username and password

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-
            8859-1">
       <title>Login</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <form method="POST" action="/login">
            User Name : <input type="text" name="username"/>
            Password: <input type="password" name="password"/>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

and the endpage `test.jsp` looks like this

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-
            8859-1">
        <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Hi
    </body>
</html>
```

The errormessage is

> Whitelabel Error Page
>   This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
>   Thu Mar 01 21:43:40 CET 2018
>   There was an unexpected error (type=Forbidden, status=403).
>   Could not verify the provided CSRF token because your session was not found.

It is run on my localhost as a http without any ssl or any other securitysettings chosen except for the Spring Boot Securitydependency in the pom.xml-file.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

The Mvc is handled by

```
package com.proj.db_proj;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import 
  org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import 
 org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
        registry.addViewController("/startpage").setViewName("startpage");
        registry.addViewController("/test").setViewName("test");
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("start");
    }
}
```

and the Websecurity with the authentication and configuration

```
package com.proj.db_proj;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.
    builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.
    web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.
    web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.¨
    web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

     @Override
         protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/", "/start").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .permitAll()
                    .and()
                .logout()
                    .permitAll();
        }

        @Autowired
        public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) 
            throws Exception {
            auth
                .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("user").roles("USER");
        }

 }
```

Anyone can see any error or know why I get the Whitelabel error page? I have followed manuals and checked tutorials and also questions here on stackoverflow without any answers.

Comment: Your login page doesn't submit the CSRF token, so you get an error. See [Spring Security Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html#csrf-include-csrf-token).

Answer (score 1):

In your error messages, you did not append csrf token.

```
Could not verify the provided CSRF token because your session was not found.
```

At spring boot security,  csrf is enabled by default. 
If you want to disable csrf, append this code to your HttpSecurity configuration. (Do not miss .and())

```
.csrf().disable();
```

Comment: Hi. Tried it but it just bounced back to login.jsp. When I followed the tutorails noone has used that command and I have seen post here on stackoverflow not recommending to disable .csrf. The only difference from my code from the tutorails is that they have used thymeleaf template but I can't see that as a problem?

Comment: If you don't want to disable csrf, then refer spring boot csrf token chapter : https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html#csrf-include-csrf-token
or  http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-csrf

Comment: And   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38004035/could-not-verify-the-provided-csrf-token-because-your-session-was-not-found-in-s   
This is the discussion about  'Could not verify the provided CSRF token because your session was not found.'  error.

Comment: Did you specify spring session management as stateless. If so specify it as if-required.

Comment: But according to the docs enablewebsecirity annotation that I got should take care of csrfhandling.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Thymeleaf namespace to actually use CSRF (which is enabled by default).

Change:

```
<form method="POST" action="/login">
```

to:

```
<form method="POST" th:action="@{/login}">
```